# Why a canvas created with Processing works fine in window mode, but it laggs awfully when ran on the browser as a background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, processing

I created a 3D dynamic mesh with Processing(Java) that works perfectly (no lag) when I run it in window mode.
Actually my objective is to set that drawing as background on a website that I'm building.
Here's the problem, when I set that, it makes lag everything and obviously the render is not what I expected.

I discovered that if I reduce the complexity of the mesh, incrementing the scale of each square (in the mesh) or reducing the width and the height, it seem it works better but still with poor results.
So I'm still wondering if i'm missing some kind of optimization outside the script like in the css file.

In my css file I just setted the canvas to works in background

```
.background{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

In my layout (Jade) I just call the scripts

```
  script(src='/js/processing-1.4.8.min.js')
  canvas.background(data-processing-sources='/js/terrain2_0.pde')
```

And here an image (in window mode) of what my mesh actually produce as 3d results. It moves using a noise function that pull up and down vertexes on the Z axis of the mesh. Actually if I try to put that on the browser it laggs really hard.
[image]

Comment: Java is faster than JavaScript. You'll have to find ways to optimize your code or simplify the animation for it to work in JavaScript.

Comment: @Zartof Have you tried [three.js](https://threejs.org/) ? It shouldn't be hard to port your processing mesh to a three.js mesh (with faces and vertices) that you can render with WebGL efficiently

Comment: Thanks guys. I found out a way to limit my matrix inspection to once per frame, so now the animation works just fine. I also set a roof of 40 FPS and that really helped a lot to obtain a fluid animation. Good tip @Kevin Workman